# Cannot test ROOM Database with Flows because of the delays

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am trying to develop a simple inventory application for myself and I am using ROOM Database with Flow as return type for the queries, so that when I update the database, the query automatically emits my list of inventory items and the UI is updated automatically.

in the DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM inventoryitem ORDER BY favourite = 0, count = 0")
    fun getInventory(): Flow<List<InventoryItem>>
```

and in the ViewModel init() block:

```
init {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            database.inventoryDao().getInventory().collect {
                inventory.value = it
            }
        }
    }
```

and the inventory is displayed in the UI, so whenever I update the ROOM database, the UI is updated automatically. It works perfectly.

I am trying to write a simple insertion test for my viewModel that tests whether upon inserting a new item into the database, my inventory will actually update itself:

```
@Test
    fun simpleInsertTest() = runTest {
        viewModel.addInventoryItem(testItems[0])
        assertEquals(viewModel.inventory.value, listOf(testItems[0]))
    }
```

This test only passes if I add a sleep(200L) inbetween the two test lines, I am guessing because the ROOM insertion and the flow collection takes some time, and the test code does not wait for it with the assertion.

Is there any better way to wait for the new emission other than using this approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Need to see your insert function in the DAO. Why is `database.inventoryDao()` a function instead of property? Looks suspicious. You should not be specifying a dispatcher to collect your flow—it won’t cause an issue in this specific case but it is unnecessary, and in some cases could cause an issue. Dispatchers.IO is for calling *blocking* functions and `collect` calls do not block—they suspend.

Comment: I can only recommend injecting your dispatchers. It brings a bit of overhead but that way in test environment you can force all your methods to work on TestDispatcher or just make them blocking.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. inventoryDao() is a function and not a property because that is how it is used in the official guide (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room). Now that you say it I wonder myself why that is, but I just went with the official way. About the dispatcher, that is a good advice, thank you, I have not thought about that, just wanted to make sure that I am not blocking the UI thread. Also injecting dispatcher is also a good idea, but even then there would be a slight delay and the test might fail, or would be flaky.

Comment: if you inject a TestDispatcher in place of IO you can use its scheduler to `advanceUntilIdle()` which ensures everything is done and there's no need to guess how much delay to add.

Answer (score 0):

Add `suspend` to insert function in DAO and wrap `addInventoryItem` to `try/catch` block. If catch fired - test failed.